# The words in slider are splitted in a inappropriate way

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a slider in `wordpress` which splits the words, like the example below.

I have the following html code:

```
<div class="box-caption--excerpt">
   <p>Compassion is “sensitivity to the pain or suffering of another, coupled with a deep desire to alleviate that suffering”. (Goetz et al, 2010)</p>
</div>
```

I tried using the following `css`, but I don't have the expected outcome.

```
.box-caption--excerpt p{
    word-space: nowrap;
}
```

Any help please?

[image]

Comment: `word-space: nowrap` is not a thing. `word-space` is the wrong property to begin with - that is for the spacing _between_ words. You probably meant `word-break` or the non-standard `word-wrap` - resp. its modern replacement, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I had to set:

```
.box-caption--excerpt p{
     line-break: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`word-break: normal;` or `word-break: keep-all` is the answer to your problem;

Comment: Thanks. None of them is working unfortunately.

Comment: Add `white-space: nowrap;`
Also try adding `display: inline-block;` to your <p> tag.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the width of the div

```
.box-caption--excerpt p{
    word-space: nowrap;
    width:"150px";
```

}